# Carousel caption used to move with slides but stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so i have a carousel caption under each slide and it used to move as the slides moved as if the entire page was a carousel but from a day to the next it just stopped and i don't know how to fix it please help.
this is my carousel code:

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="images/wisp.png" alt="WISP" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("wisp.html") ?>       
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/linkme.png" alt="linkme" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("linkme.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/zainent.png" alt="zain" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("zainent.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/tahadi.png" alt="tahadi" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("tahadi.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/onelife.png" alt="onelife" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("onelife.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


<div class="item">
    <img src="images/alavina.png" alt="alavina" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("alavina.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/iha.png" alt="iha" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("iha.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/runnuts.png" alt="runnuts" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("runnuts.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/oliviafred.png" alt="oliviafred" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("oliviafred.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/bandicoot.png" alt="bandicoot" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("bandicoot.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/bassama.png" alt="bassama" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("bassama.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>      
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>     
</a>
</div>
</div>       
     <div id="text"></div>
```

and this is my script:

```
        $('#text').html($('.active > .carousel-captionn').html());
       $('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
      $('#text').html($('.active > .carousel-captionn').html());
      });
```

and this is the css for carousel-captionn:

```
.carousel-captionn{
        display: none !important;
}
```

if i use the normal "carousel-caption" from bootstrap, the caption is aligning with the slides (going over them)
thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Do you have a live example of this issue? Not quite sure what the problem is here as you said you an use the normal bootstrap class

Comment: @itodd if i use the normal bootstrap class, the text inside the caption overlaps the slides pictures this is why i had to change the class. the problem is i want the caption to move with the slides as if the whole page was a carousel and this was working before but it just stopped working unexpectedly and i can't get it to work again anymore